# Windows Phone XML and HTML elements

Tags: html, xml, parsing, windows-phone

I am at the moment doing a practice project for a friend who asks that I create a phone app to view certain website news. Now, I've done this with pulling the RSS and it's just simple XML parsing, but I've hit a small problem when one XML element has HTML elements. Like this:

```
<description>  
Lorem ipsum Dolor Sit Amet <a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</description>
```

Now, I have TextBlocks on my Listbox which are bound to class items and I've created one for this Description which is basically the news content.

```
string description;
public string Description
{
  get { return description; }
  set { description = value; }
}
```

And

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Width="430" TextWrapping="wrap" FontSize="20" />
```

Everything prints out fine but because it's a textblock it prints out these html elements in text. I am looking for a general tip how to either remove all these HTML tags from the element or to print out HTML elements on the phone. I've read something about doing it as a WebBrowser, but removing it's background and everything seems kinda tricky, but if you have any general tips throw them at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display html in a textblock so there is no really workaround to launch this link.
You can try with a regex to supress the `<a></a>` elements

Like you said, webBrowser can be tricky, but if you want to be able to click on the FB link, I'll suggest that, and you can add an image in the background, there is a lot of workaround for that.